# Counting elements for each group using Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I'm trying to group and count the frequency of terms for each group in PigLatin, but I'm having some troubles to figure it out how to do it.

I have a collection of objects with the following schema:

```
{cluster_id: bytearray,terms: chararray}
```

And here is some samples

```
(10, smerter)
(10, graviditeten)
(10, smerter)
(10, smerter)
(10, udemærket)    
(20, eis feuer)
(20, herunterladen schau)
(20, download gratis)
(20, download gratis) 
(30, anschauen kinofilm)
(30, kauf rechnung)
(30, kauf rechnung)
(30, versandkostenfreie lieferung)
(30, kostenlose)
(30, kostenlose)
(30, kostenlose)
```

the result I m trying to get is something like this

```
(10, smerter, 3)
(10, graviditeten, 2)
(10, udemærket, 1)
(20, download gratis, 2)
(20, eis feuer, 1)
(20, herunterladen schau, 1)    
(30, kostenlose, 3)
(30, kauf rechnung, 2)
(30, anschauen kinofilm, 1)
(30, versandkostenfreie lieferung, 1)
```

What would be the best way to do that?
The following code groups by id and count the terms, but I wanted to count the terms for each group.

```
by_clusters = GROUP sample_data by cluster_id;
by_clusters_terms_count = FOREACH by_clusters GENERATE group as cluster_id, COUNT($1);
```

I make the grouping like this I end up with an object with the following schema

```
by_clusters: {group: bytearray,sample_data: {(cluster_id: bytearray,terms: chararray)}}
```

Now, I get to the point to actually count the terms inside the 'sample_data' tuple.
I'm thinking about nested foreach, but I still didn't get it how could I apply it in this case.
The code would be something like the following:

```
result = FOREACH by_clusters {

--count terms here, I don't know how

-- compiler gives me an error here
c = GROUP $1 BY terms; -- 
d = FOREACH c GENERATE COUNT(b), group;

GENERATE cluster_id, d;
}
```

Error I get:

> ERROR 1200:   Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near '$1

Finally, I think I'm close, but I'm unable to solve it. 
I don't believe I'll have to write an UDF in this case.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think that what you want to do is simply group by `cluster_id` and `terms`.

You were very close to the result with you first try, just add `terms` to your group :

```
by_clusters = GROUP sample_data by (cluster_id, terms);
by_clusters_terms_count = FOREACH by_clusters GENERATE FLATTEN(group) as (cluster_id, terms), COUNT($1);
```

I hope I understood well what you want!

Comment: Question: why does COUNT($1) work as opposed to COUNT(terms)? E.g., does COUNT($1) mean "count the number of instances of each unique pair (cluster_id, terms)"?

Comment: Can someone help me understand how the lowercase "group" in "FLATTEN(group)" is used? I can't seem to find a reference.. all results are pointing to GROUP .. BY :(

Answer (score 1):

You can replace  COUNT(*$1*) with COUNT(***sample_data***) as well.

```
   by_clusters = GROUP sample_data by (cluster_id, terms);
    by_clusters_terms_count = FOREACH by_clusters GENERATE FLATTEN(group) as (cluster_id, terms), COUNT(*sample_data*);
```

**michael-xu** here is the difference :

*FLATTENed result:*

```
by_clusters_terms_count = FOREACH by_clusters GENERATE FLATTEN(group) , COUNT($1);
```

*result : (10, smerter,3)*

*Not FLATTENed result:*

```
by_clusters_terms_count = FOREACH by_clusters GENERATE group , COUNT($1);
```

*result : ((10, smerter),3)*

The key field is named “group”. Here is the schema for by_clusters_terms_count

{**group**:(cluster_id: bytearray,terms: chararray),long}